# How to read in text files and copy them to a string array?

Tags: c, file, io

I'm trying to open a file called `dictonary.txt` and copy its contents to a string array. But I forget how to do it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    char dict[999][15];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    while(feof (fp))
    {
            
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT:** There are 999 words in the file and all of them have 15 characters or less.

Comment: [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?r=SearchResults&s=1|404.0572) and `while (feof(file))` doesn't make sense

Comment: It will depend on the structure of the input file, but [`fgets()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) and [`fscanf()` or `sscanf()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) will be useful.

Comment: @pmg It is actually `while(feof (fp))` here. No `!` and it is worse.

Comment: do you want up to 999 words shorter than 15 chars each... or up to 15 words shorter than 999 chars each (as your code suggests)?

Comment: Also you should check if the result if `fopen()` is not `NULL` before doing further works.

Comment: " i forget how to do it." - lickily you don't have to remember that stuff - there are references: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/   You might at least include a fragment of the file content.  It is line, space or comma delimited for example.

Comment: @Kazumi411 I did change the file name, IDK if you missed it, corrected it now.

Comment: @anastaciu I did tried that, still didn't work. i made sure the txt file is in the project file so what could be wrong?

Comment: @Kazumi411 it should work flawlessly, I added some more code to help you pinpoint the problem, I also added a live sample, check it https://wandbox.org/permlink/TDDyZXswA07imf9a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments `while(!feof (fp))` will not work as intended, you are also missing the negator but that's beside the point, a simple way to do this is to use `fgets` and take advantage of its return value to detect the end of the file, as it returns `NULL` when there are no more lines to read:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char dict[999][15];
    size_t ind; // store the index of last read line

    FILE *fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");

    if (fp != NULL) // check if the file was succefully opened
    {
        // read each line until he end, or the array bound is reached
        for (ind = 0; fgets(dict[ind], sizeof dict[0], fp) && ind < sizeof dict / sizeof dict[0]; ind++)
        {
            dict[ind][strcspn(dict[ind], "\n")] = '\0'; // remove newline from the buffer, optional
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < ind; i++) // test print
        {
            puts(dict[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
    }
}
```

Note that this will also read empty lines, **i.e.** lines with `\n` only or other blank characters.

[**Test sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TDDyZXswA07imf9a)

Comment: Also be careful: `fgets()` will put the newline character read to the buffer, so you may want to remove that before further processing.

Comment: @MikeCAT added an option to remove it, also a note that *blank* lines will also be parsed.

Comment: I just posted a function to have fgets without the new line if you want to avoid parsing your string twice: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/258772/fgets-without-the-line-return your insights are welcome! @MikeCAT and anastaciu

Comment: note the edit in the question correcting the array dimension order.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char dict[999][15];
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");

    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", dict[i]) != EOF)
            i++;

    // i is your length of the list now so you can print all words with
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            printf("%s ", dict[j]);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of != EOF, you can also do == 1 because fscanf returns a value of scanned things. So if you do:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", dict[i]);
```

it will return 1 if a word is successfully scanned. And it won't when it reaches the end of the file. So you can do it that way too.